# Nitrous IO desktop not syncing files

Tags: synchronization, desktop-application, nitrousio

I can't get Nitrous IO desktop downloading my remote files on the server into my machine, when I launch it for the first time.

I've just downloaded Nitrous io desktop, logged in, had a look at my boxes, but when I switch "Files sync" on, it says only "Syncing", and nerver ends.

Furthermore, in the Nitrous folder, I can only see .unison folder dans default.prf file. That's all.
No traces of my files.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue with Windows. This is how I solved it:

When I installed Nitrous.io Desktop the application scanned my computer for existing rsa keys. I believe it found them; however, I had set up my private key to have a passphrase. It seems that the passphrase was the issue with the file Sync. The "Shell" connection worked properly but it prompted me for my passphrase before connecting; this gave me a clue.

This is how I solved it:

1. Go to Nitrous.io Desktop Preferences by right clicking on the notification area icon.
2. Check the rsa_key files being used.
3. Find and delete the old rsa keys files.
4. Click on rescan
5. Generate new SSH keys from within the Nitrous.io Desktop App
6. Register them.
7. Restart the Nitrous App.
8. Syncing should be working now.

Comment: Not working for me. It says "Monitoring" but only .unison folder is there.

Comment: Can you please help me with a Nitrous issue, it is also a sync problem, but not the one mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331349/nitrous-desktop-cannot-sync-files-due-to-unison-error

Answer (score 1):

I had to follow Rafael's instructions, and ALSO also add a windows firewall rule allowing the Nitrous Desktop exe through. It would be great to know what ports/protocol it's using so the rule could be less permissive.

Answer (score 1):

Putting files in the ~/workspace directory as mentioned is what made it work for me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Nitrious was recovering from heartbleed vulnerability recently, so they need to shut down their servers. Now sync works just fine, I tested.

Make sure your files are in ~/workspace directory. 
Files in root folder are not being synchronized.