# Nitrous Desktop cannot sync files due to unison error

Tags: synchronization, desktop-application, nitrousio

I am using Nitrous Desktop (Windows 8.1 x64). Whenever I try to sync, there is an error:

```
Error: server: end_of_file exception raised in loading archive (this indicates a bug)
```

What all I tried:

1. Re-create ssh keys
2. Delete .unison folder

What should be done here to sync normally? Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the .unison folder on the box did the trick. What I was trying to do is to delete the .unison folder on my local machine.